# Esxi Var/log pointing to scratch partition?

Tags: linux, vmware

Is Esxi Var/log pointing to scratch partition?
If yes all the logs in var/log folder(hostd, vpxa, fdm etc) will be deleted after the esxi reboot if scratch partition is on RAM disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not configured scratch partition , the logs will be in RAM disk and it will be deleted post reboot of ESXi.

The below article will help you configure scratch location on ESXi

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1033696

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What if I redirect var/log to a datastore or a syslog server, then do I not have to worry about logs being deleted even if scratch is on RAM? Also does your reply mean that everything in var/log is actually writing on scratch partition?

Comment: The scratch partition is created automatically durin the installation, if it is not configured properly, you can configure it on a datastore or redirect the logs to a remote syslog server. In this case (if u configured datastore or syslog) you can reboot the ESXi and the logs will be persistent across reboots .